# Return script content that has src attribute

Tags: javascript

i am having a bit of a problem here and i don't even know if it is possible at all, here's my dilema:

I have this script code:

```
<script id='script1' src='http://link.to.js'></script>
```

While using firebug, i can clearly see that the script has bee loaded between those tags, like this

```
<script id='script1' src='http://link.to.js'>
  function something(){
    alert('hi');}
</script>
```

What i want to do is, by means of another script, get the content between those tags, something like

```
var x = document.getElementById('script1').innerHtml;
document.getElementById('somedividhere').innerHtml = x;
```

That works perfectly WHEN the code is already part of the html, not when its loaded from src.

I have been looking for this for hours and i have not found any hint, hope someone can help me on this.

Comment: When is the latter code executed? You have to put it in the window.onload event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Firebug only shows you that for convenience sake. If you want to get the code from the script, you'll have to use AJAX.

You could do something like this:

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var scriptcontent = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            //Do something with the content
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", document.getElementById('script1').src, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

Just a few notes:

1. This will only work for scripts
   located on your site due to the
   [same origin
   policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).
2. I took the ajax code from [this
   site](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-javascript.php)
   and modified it.
3. This would be a lot
   easier with
   [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/)

Comment: RE #3: or Dojo, or MooTools, or Prototype JS, or YUI, or any other JS library worth its salt out there :)  Also, just to make sure it's clear to the OP, this will essentially involve asking for the same script an extra time just so you can get its contents in a way you can directly work with it.  I'm thinking that a direct way is not possible though.

Comment: @Ken Franqueiro: Indeed, but jQuery is what I use so... <shameless plug> :)

Comment: I see, well that was perfectly explained, doesn't fulfill my needs but since what i want is clearly not achievable (cross domain policy), it was a perfect answer, thanks!

Comment: Also, out of curiosity and just for more info, couldn't the script be loaded into browser cache and read it from there? It would certainly bypass the policy

Comment: @user524695: Well, theoretically, the browser may cache it into a file on your hard drive but I'm sure reading that through JavaScript would have similar security issues (assuming you could  figure out a) the folder for the cache for the current browser; b) the actual name of the file; and c) if the browser caches things in this manner.) I don't see it as a viable option.